# Convert Json array into csv using Nifi

Tags: arrays, json, apache-nifi

I'm looking to convert JSON with an array to csv format. The number of elements inside the array is dynamic for each row. I tried using this flow, ( attached the flow file xml on the post ).

GetFile --> ConvertRecord --> UpdateAttribute --> PutFile

Are there any other alternatives?

JSON format:

```
{  
   "LogData":{  
      "Location":"APAC",
      "product":"w1"
   },
   "Outcome":[  
      {  
         "limit":"0",
         "pri":"3",
         "result":"pass"
      },
      {  
         "limit":"1",
         "pri":"2",
         "result":"pass"
      },
      {  
         "limit":"5",
         "priority":"1",
         "result":"fail"
      }
   ],
   "attr":{  
      "vers":"1",
      "datetime":"2018-01-10 00:36:00"
   }
}
```

Expected output in csv:

```
location,   product,    limit,  pri,    result, vers,   datetime
APAC        w1          0       3       pass    1       2018-01-10 00:36:00
APAC        w1          1       2       pass    1       2018-01-10 00:36:00
APAC        w1          5       1       fail    1       2018-01-10 00:36:00
```

Output from the attached flow:

```
LogData,Outcome,attr
"MapRecord[{product=w1, Location=APAC}]","[MapRecord[{limit=0, result=pass, pri=3}], MapRecord[{limit=1, result=pass, pri=2}], MapRecord[{limit=5, result=fail}]]","MapRecord[{datetime=2018-01-10 00:36:00, vers=1}]"
```

[image]

ConvertRecord Config:
[image]

JSONTReeReader Controller service Config:
[image]
CSVRecordSetWriter Controller service Config:
[image]
Avroschmeregistry Contoller service config:
[image]

Avro schema:
    {  "name": "myschema",  "type": "record",  "namespace": "myschema",  "fields": [{"name": "LogData","type": {  "name": "LogData",  "type": "record",  "fields": [{  "name": "Location",  "type": "string"},{  "name": "product",  "type": "string"}  ]}},{"name": "Outcome","type": {  "type": "array",  "items": {"name": "Outcome_record","type": "record","fields": [  {"name": "limit","type": "string"  },  {"name": "pri","type": ["string","null"]  },  {"name": "result","type": "string"  }]  }}},{"name": "attr","type": {  "name": "attr",  "type": "record",  "fields": [{  "name": "vers",  "type": "string"},{  "name": "datetime",  "type": "string"}  ]}}  ]}

Comment: Could you update the question with `Record Reader/Writer` controller service schemas?

Comment: updated with the screenshots of all the configuration and the avro schema details.